# What does the 2/0 directionality mean

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to use adum1200 isolator.
I want to know what they mean by 2/0 directionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of channels alone does not completely specifiy how you can use the chip.
The [ADUM1200](http://www.analog.com/en/products/interface-isolation/isolation/standard-digital-isolators/adum1200.html)/[ADUM1201](http://www.analog.com/en/products/interface-isolation/isolation/standard-digital-isolators/adum1201.html) web pages show the difference:

> ADUM1200: Dual-Channel Digital Isolator (**2/0** Channel Directionality)
>
> [image: ADUM1200]
>
> ADUM1201: Dual-Channel Digital Isolator (**1/1** Channel Directionality)
>
> [image: ADUM1201]

Comment: in other words it's  information I already knew but expressed ina different way.